# Magento 2.1.7 custom module UpgradeSchema not adding column

Tags: magento2, module, xml, upgradeschema

I'm not able to add new column to existing table
UpgradeSchema.php:

```
 namespace Company\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{

    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        //handle all possible upgrade versions
        $tableName = $setup->getTable('test_table');
        if(!$context->getVersion()) {
            //no previous version found
        }

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.5') < 0) {
            $connection = $setup->getConnection();
            $connection->addColumn(
                $tableName,
                'test_test_1',
                ['type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'nullable' => false,
                    'default' => '',
                    'afters' => 'created_at'],
                'Test 1'
            );
        }

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.6') < 0) {
            $connection = $setup->getConnection();
            $connection->addColumn(
                $tableName,
                'test_test_2',
                ['type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'nullable' => false,
                    'default' => '',
                    'afters' => 'created_at'],
                'Test 2'
            );
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

My module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Company_Module" setup_version="1.1.5">

</module>
```

Can anyone give some advice please! Thanks.

Comment: @Manthan Dave  any idea?

Comment: @Manthan Dave Yes I do have setup_version set to '1.1.5' and the table "setu_module" does changes when I run the setup:upgrade but the column doesn't get added!

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and it was due to `UpgradeData.php` don't no why but I have rewritten to `InstallData.php` and now it worked as I expected, So  no deletion entry from `setup_module` is necessary if you do unless a getVersion() check is done it will duplicate the data.

My `setup_module` entry has:

```
schema_version:1.1.5 
data_version:1.1.5
```

So I changed `setup_version` My module.xml to:

```
setup_version="1.1.6"
```

And My UpgradeSchema `version_compare` to:

```
 if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.1.6') < 0) {...}
```

Now the new column is added.